# Rails 4 and Coffeescript Simple Ajax return html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have a simple Coffeescript method calling a controllers action:

```
  retrieveFeedData: (selected) ->
    $.post 'demo_feeds',
      feed_title: selected.text()
      feed_url: selected.val()
      (data) -> $('body').append data
```

Here is the route I created:

```
post :demo_feeds, to: 'feeds#demo_feeds', as: 'demo_feeds'
```

Here is the Rails method:

```
  def demo_feeds
    if request.xhr?
      # respond to Ajax request
    else
      # respond to normal request
    end
  end
```

How do I return the content of the actions view file and pass it back to the `data` variable in Coffeescript?

**EDIT:**
I also found that `feeds` controller also has some resources setup:

```
  resources :feeds, only: [:index, :edit, :create, :update] do
    resources :entries, only: [:index], controller: :feeds_entries
    collection do
      get :view_unread
      get :view_all
      get :auto_update
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to work around this without messing up the resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to add remove the layout and things worked fine:

```
  def demo_feeds
    render :layout => nil 
  end
```